# displaying the tesseract version (iOS)

Tags: ios, tesseract

I finally managed to compile a tesseract library for iOS.
I've replaced 3.01 with 3.02.02 and was wondering if anyone knew how to show the tesseract version (I just want to make sure it's really updated).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TessBaseAPI` has a method, `static const char* Version()` that "[r]eturns the version identifier as a static string". So you'd just need to log that, put it into a `UILabel` via e.g. `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", yourTesseractInstance->Version()]`, or output it by any other means.